# Mysql sum on total in multiselect

Tags: mysql, sum, multi-select

I want the total from total_price_incl_tax and paid. If i use the first query i get the rows from all selected column. This works fine. But i want only the totals so i changed the query.

```
SELECT 
total_price_incl_tax,
(SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') as paid
FROM sales_invoices AS s 
WHERE s.administration_id = 10605 
AND `s`.`delete` = '0' 
AND `s`.`concept` = '0' 
AND `s`.`subscription` = '0' 
AND (`total_price_incl_tax` <> (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') OR (SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') IS NULL)
```

The problem whit the second query is that the sum for the subquery (paid) is not correct. This contains the value of the last row and not the total.

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*),
SUM(total_price_incl_tax) AS total,
(SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') as paid
FROM sales_invoices AS s 
WHERE s.administration_id = 10605 
AND `s`.`delete` = '0' 
AND `s`.`concept` = '0' 
AND `s`.`subscription` = '0' 
AND (`total_price_incl_tax` <> (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') OR (SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') IS NULL)
```

Any idea how to sole this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just encapsulate:

```
SELECT
  count(*),
  SUM(total_price_incl_tax),
  SUM(paid)
FROM
(
   SELECT 
   total_price_incl_tax,
   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') as paid
   FROM sales_invoices AS s 
   WHERE s.administration_id = 10605 
   AND `s`.`delete` = '0' 
   AND `s`.`concept` = '0' 
   AND `s`.`subscription` = '0' 
   AND (`total_price_incl_tax` <> (SELECT SUM(`amount`) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') OR (SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum FROM `invoice_payments` WHERE `invoice_id` = s.id AND invoice_type = 'sales') IS NULL)
) t
```